# Доступ к CIFS папке из django

Tags: django, apache2

Проблема в следующем.
Есть web-сервер ubuntu+apache2 на нем крутится сайт на django. И есть второй сервер - полка на ubuntu на котором расшарена smb-папка, которая на web-сервере смонтирована через cifs прямо в папку с проектом django рядом со static/. В настройках сайта в файлах Apache прописан алиас media/ на эту папку. **Requaires all granted** прописан. В settings.py прописал MEDIA_URL  и MEDIA_ROOT на эту папку. на всех папках и файлах выставлены www-data:www-data. Папка так же монтируется www-data:www-data. для проверки на всех папках выставил права 777. Для той же проверки и на самой полке для всех папок и файлов в расшаренной папке выставил www-data:www-data с правами 777. При всех этих настройках   `<img src="/media/image.jpg" />` не отображается. если пытаюсь напрямую обратиться к картинке сервер выдает ошибку ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. При этом если я размещаю картинку не в шаре а в локальной папке  (с теми же настройками) все отображается прекрасно. Хранить файлы в локальной папке не вариант так как на шару стекаются изображения из разных источников. И для них требуется достаточно большой объем хранилища. Собственно вопрос: что я не учел? Синтаксические ошибки в настройках исключаем. С веб-сервера я без проблем захожу на шару. Создаю/редактирую/удаляю папки и файлы. apache2 запущен www-data